# Need help to write SQL query as a linq expression

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I'm new here, so I apologise if I made any mistakes. I have written the following SQL code to retrieve the number of submissions by each users in a specific faculty.

```
declare @faculty as int = 1
SELECT COUNT(ew_student.sName) AS Submissions, ew_student.sEmail, ew_faculty.nFaculty
FROM ew_student 
INNER JOIN ew_submission ON ew_student.sId = ew_submission.sId INNER JOIN
                            ew_faculty ON ew_student.sFaculty = ew_faculty.fId
WHERE ew_faculty.fId = @faculty
GROUP BY ew_student.sEmail, ew_faculty.nFaculty
```

Running this query through MS SQL Server Management returns the results I am expecting, however on my ASP.NET web application I am having difficulties writing the LINQ expression.

My database context is called "db". Here's what I have so far, but it returns the wrong results.

```
var stats = from ew_submissions in db.ew_submissions
            where ew_submissions.ew_student.ew_faculty.fId == facultyId
            group new { ew_submissions.ew_student, ew_submissions.ew_student.ew_faculty } by new
            {
                ew_submissions.ew_student.sEmail,
                ew_submissions.ew_student.sName,
                ew_submissions.ew_student.ew_faculty.nFaculty

            } into g
            select new
            {
                Submissions = g.Count(),
                g.Key.sName


            };

return stats.ToList();
```

I want to retrieve how many submissions a specific users has made, however the LINQ expression above always returns 1 for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You switched the places of what you want to group (values) and by what (keys):

```
var stats = from ew_submissions in db.ew_submissions
            where ew_submissions.ew_student.ew_faculty.fId == facultyId
            group ew_submissions.ew_student.sName by new
            {
                ew_submissions.ew_student.sEmail,
                ew_submissions.ew_student.ew_faculty.nFaculty
            } into g
            select new
            {
                Submissions = g.Count(),
                g.Key.sName
            };

return stats.ToList();
```

Also see that when you are grouping by the `sEmail` and `nFaculty` you do not want to also group by `sName` because then you will probably get many results of count 1.

Comment: Hi Gilad, good to see you again :) But `g.Key.sName` not gonna work in `select`.

Comment: @IvanStoev - Yap :) wasn't here for a long time. And ops :) missed that - the original SQL does not use the actual text of the name :)